# ASP.NET MVC jquery.fancybox undefined Error

Tags: jquery, html

In our asp.net MVC view page,we use jquery.fancybox javascript file. I got jquery.fancybox undefined error when browsing the page.
The following the html content from that page(I copy this content from firebug web browser tool).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="fancybox-margin fancybox-lock" lang="en">
<head>
<body data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar" data-spy="scroll" data-twttr-rendered="true">
<div class="jump meadhead_bar">
<div class="jump logo_bar">
<div id="panel" style="margin-top: 5px;">
<div class="container content">
<div class="footer_text">Copyright © 2013 - All rights reserved</div>
<div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 162px;">
<div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 162px;">
<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block;">
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-ajax fancybox-opened" tabindex="-1" style="width: 657px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 303px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible;">
<div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;">
<div class="fancybox-outer">
<div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: auto; width: 627px; height: 282px;">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<meta content="" name="description">
<meta content="" name="author">
<style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/docs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/tm_docs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/prettify.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/no-more-tables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/Content/css/jquery.multiselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ServiceStack/js/jquery.countdown.css">
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/prettify.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-transition.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-alert.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-modal.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-tab.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-popover.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-button.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-collapse.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-carousel.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-affix.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/application.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/jquery.cookie.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/superfish.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js">
<script src="/ServiceStack/js/json3.js">
<script>
<div class="content">
<div class="content_">
<div class="page_title_bg">
<div class="content_container">
<form method="post" action="/ServiceStack/TaxiOperator/OperatorPopUp?Length=0">
<div class="content_">
<div id="no-more-tables" class="tbl">
<input id="oppage" type="hidden" value="1">
<input id="oprecordperpage" type="hidden" value="5">
<input id="optotalpage" type="hidden" value="2">
<table id="optable" class="table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
<thead class="cf">
<tr>
<th class="header" style="width:5%"></th>
<th class="header" style="width:20%">Taxi Operator</th>
<th class="header" style="width:20%">Company Name</th>
<th class="header" style="width:20%">Country</th>
<th class="header" style="width:25%">Key Contact Person</th>
<th class="header" style="width:10%">Number Of Taxi</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td data-title="Taxi Operator">
<td data-title="Company">
<td data-title="Country"> Myanmar</td>
<td data-title="Key Contact Person"></td>
<td class="numeric" data-title="Number Of Taxi">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="background-color: #a5a5a5; display: block">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="controls span3 optbtn">
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<input id="hidRecord" type="hidden">
<input id="hidRecordName" type="hidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" title="Close"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following post resolves my problem:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-when-opening-fancybox-for-the-second-time